# What's wrong with this C# CodeSnippet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-snippets

I've made snippets before but I must be overlooking something really simple; I cannot figure out where the error is in this snippet...

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
 <Header>
  <Title>Throw NotImplementedException()</Title>
  <Author>olaffuB</Author>
  <Shortcut>nie</Shortcut>
  <Description>Quickly add a new NotImplementedException() to code.</Description>
  <SnippetTypes>
   <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
  </SnippetTypes>
 </Header>
 <Snippet>
  <Declarations>
   <Literal>
    <ID>TODO</ID>
    <Default></Default>
   </Literal>
  </Declarations>
  <Code Language="C#">
   <![CDATA[throw new NotImplementedException("$TODO$");    // TODO: $TODO$]]>
  </Code>
 </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Basically, when I got to import the snippet, it says that it is "invalid". The file name is "nie.snippet". Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author tag is not allowed as it seems to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
  <Header>
    <Title>class</Title>
    <Shortcut>class</Shortcut>
    <Description>Expansion snippet for class</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal default="true">
        <ID>name</ID>
        <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
        <Default>MyClass</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
   <Code Language="csharp" Format="CData">
    <![CDATA[class $name$
    {
      $selected$$end$
    }]]>
   </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379562%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `<CodeSnippet>` tag isn't closed. Append `</CodeSnippet>` to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone. The missing end tag was my fault from copying onto the Stack. I took out the author tag and added the xml... tag to the top. Also, I had "C#" where "CSharp" should have been. Here is a final working version of the snippet!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <Title>Lemme Throw NotImplementedException()</Title>
        <Shortcut>nie</Shortcut>
        <Description>Allows an extreme coder to quickly add a new NotImplementedException to their code.</Description>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>TODO</ID>
                <Default>###</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="CSharp" >
            <![CDATA[throw new NotImplementedException("$TODO$");    // TODO: $TODO$]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have closed the

```
<CodeSnippet>
```

Tag.